# Detect if the incoming call is roaming

Tags: android, roaming

Are there any ways to determine if the incoming call is roaming whether regional, national, or international? I'm using `libphonenumber` to handle some of my call cases but I don't know if it can solve my problem as there is no documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method isNetworkRoaming():

```
private final TelephonyManagertelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) yourContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()
```